# How to check if Image Quality is Low

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin-extension

I am developing a PhotoBook app where I need to notify the user if they add a low-resolution image. I just need to show a "Low-Resolution Image, Printing may be affected" warning as chatbooks app do.

Comment: You can check through image size. like 

long length = file.length() / 1024;

Comment: how can you explain

Comment: you can set a condition like if image size is < 100 kb then shows an alert message.

Comment: Check https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71726/how-can-i-detect-if-an-image-is-of-poor-quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024));     
if (file_size < 100){
   Log.v(TAG, "Low resolution image");
 }else{
  Log.v(TAG, "");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert image into bitmap and check its height and width and with this its help you to check the image resolution. 
if image is from drawable,

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.back);
 bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight();
```

if image from uri

```
  Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = 
  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
  bitmap.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight();
```

make a validation if image height and width less than your need than show your alert

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Bitmap object, you can check for bitmap.getWidth() and getHeigth()

Answer (score 0):

You can check the width and height of the image and thus you can decide which resolution is appropriate to classify it as low quality.

```
public void checkQuality() {
    String filePathTmp = new File("").getAbsolutePath();//getCanonicalPath();
    //notice you must use you image path
    Path filePath = Paths.get(filePathTmp, "\\YOUR\\PARTH\\IMAGE.png").normalize(); 

    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(filePath.toString());
    int height = imageIcon.getIconHeight();
    int width = imageIcon.getIconWidth();
    System.out.println("HEIGHT: " + height + "--" + "WIDTH" + width);

    //change values, consider your own criteria low quality
    if (height <100 || width <100){
        System.out.println("Low quality");
    }
}
```